# Adding a sibling record via Visualforce in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, action, urlfor

**Scenario**

Custom object Basket__c is the Master of two Detail custom objects: Fruit__c and Vegetable__c.

Visualforce page vfAddVegetableFromFruitPage is embedded via standard Page Layout functionality in the Fruit page. This Visualforce page has an "Add New Vegetable" link that is created as follows:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Vegetable__c.New, null, [Vegetable_Color__c = 'Green'])}">Add New Vegetable</apex:outputLink>
```

As can be seen, this line simply creates the link, sets the verbiage, and prepopulates a field.

**The problem**

In SF Classic, this works fine.

In SF Lightning, it works okay in that an "Add New Vegetable" modal appears, but unfortunately the Vegetable Color field is not prepopulated. In fact, no values are received properly when passed in this way. I believe that the cause of this is due to Lightning not playing nice with URL hacks, which this is a flavor of.

**But what about using an Action?**

I have tried adding a new Action on the Fruit page; unfortunately, I don't get Vegetable as an option in the "Target Object" dropdown, since Vegetable is a sibling, and not a Detail, of Fruit.

**Any ideas?**

That sums things up in a nutshell. Am I missing something basic? Thank you.